# aws Lambda to invalidate CloudFront on S3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I have 10-50 files upload at the same time. Lambda triggers an event for every updated file (if file size changed).

So instead of invalidating one by one 50x I'd like to run the wildcard `“*”` character once at the end of the upload.

Anyone can shed some light on how to accomplish that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your lambda function knows whether CloudFront should invalidate or not but does not know when should that happen exactly.

In that case, you could return a boolean flag (e.g., `mustInvalidate`) as part of the response to indicate that an invalidation request should be created. Then, your application (or whatever initiated the batch upload request) can create the `/target-location/*` invalidation request as soon as the upload batch completes.

Answer (score 0):

In your Lambda function use the [AWS SDK for CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html) to invalidate the distribution using the sing wildcard '/*'.

```
var params = {
  DistributionId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  InvalidationBatch: { /* required */
    CallerReference: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    Paths: { /* required */
      Quantity: 0, /* required */
      Items: [
        'STRING_VALUE',
        /* more items */
      ]
    }
  }
};
cloudfront.createInvalidation(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Note: Make sure the IAM role attached to the Lambda function has necessary privileges to perform the invalidate action.

Comment: Yeah, but wouldn't this be called 50x?