# Automatically invalidate cloudfront after s3 file changes

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

We have an s3 bucket which we update using an ftp app. Every time we update the bucket, we update almost all the files there.
We wish to automatically invalidate those objects after the files are updated.
How can we do it?(aws lambda?) We want to do 1 invalidation(*) on all the files at once and not perform invalidations on each file as we it is expensive
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Amazon S3 send invalidation signals to CloudFront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783009/does-amazon-s3-send-invalidation-signals-to-cloudfront)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783009/does-amazon-s3-send-invalidation-signals-to-cloudfront and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690059/aws-lambda-to-invalidate-cloudfront-on-s3-upload